# Why does the Unsuported Class Version Error while using Recursion Method in Java?

Tags: java

I'm learning about the Recursion Method. I downloaded the script, compiled it and tried to execute it.

This is the script

```
public class Factorial{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num = Scanner.getInt("Ingrese su numero para calcular su factorial");

        System.out.println( factorial(num) );
    }

     static long factorial(int num) {
        if (num < 0) {
            return 1;
        }

        return num * factorial(num - 1); 
    }
}
```

Compiling works fine, but when I try to execute it, the CMD shows me this:

```
C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop>java Prueba
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Prueba has been
compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0),
this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Basically, I think it says that the file was compiled with a higher version than the Java Runtime version (*note: I don't know what Java Runtime means*), and that's way I can't execute it.

This are my *javac* and *java* version (I don't know if this helps):

```
C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop>javac -version
javac 14

C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop>java -version
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

I not sure about the meaning of this errors or how to fix them. I hope you can understand my problem and thanks in advance!

PD: I'm not very good at speaking English, so sorry if there is something grammatically wrong in this question ;)

Comment: Your compiler is version 14, while your runtime ("java.exe") is version 1.8. There is something wrong with your path environment variable perhaps, although starting with Java 9, the JDK and JRE are bundled together, so I don't know why javac.exe was found in a different directory from java.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using java 14 (version 58.0) to compile the code and you are running it on java 1.8 (version 52.0)

Java runtime means JRE. I think you have JDK 14 and JRE 1.8. Most likely you have messed up java installation. I would suggest you uninstall the current installation and reinstall. You can install [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) or any other OpenJDK distribution like [AdoptOpen](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)

Comment: The only thing I had to do was uninstalling the java 1.8 version. Thanks!